# Clip a line by a polygon in Javascript

Tags: javascript, geometry, data-visualization, trigonometry

I've evaluated various different libraries to attempt and find a solution that allows me to take an arbitrary line and clip it by a polygon.

What I would like to do is take the line between A and B and clip it with the square, with the result being the coordinates C, D. Please note this is a naive example and many-sided polygons will actually be used.

[image]

Libraries evaluated that only do polygon-to-polygon boolean operations
https://github.com/alexbol99/flatten-js
https://npm.io/package/polygon-clipping
https://github.com/velipso/polybooljs

I'm in need of a technique or library that could perform this operation. As always, any help would be greatly appreciated!

After implementing the solution below I quickly found some issues that will be hard to overcome. My next step is finding the middle point between two intersections and determining if that is inside the polygon.
[image]

Update:
[image]

Finding the middlepoint and determining whether it's inside of the polygon works for segments with a beginning and and end. However, it is non-trivial to have multi-segment lines. The algorithm could do intersection detection on each individual segment, but it would be quite costly.

Comment: I think the best (or less worst) option is to find the intersections between segment AB and every segment in the polygon. For a not-convex polygon there may be many intersections.

Comment: Why can't you use flatten-js? That library has classes for lines and multilines (connected paths of edges). It has intersection built-in already, and you can use the `contains()` method of the `Polygon` class with a `Point` object in order to determine if the midpoint is inside of the polygon.

Comment: Flatten-js only does boolean operations on polygons, while multi-lines exist they arent a valid option.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the polygon P as an array of line segments (four numbers per segment because there are two endpoints with two coordinates each) and the coordinates of A and B. We would like to find the coordinates of all intersections between segment AB and the segments in the polygon.

You could simply test each segment of the polygon for if and where it intersects with AB. This will give you all of the `C, D, ...` points. Here's an option for such an algorithm (in js):

```js
function intersection(ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy, dx, dy) {
  // ax, ay, bx, and by are the coordinates of the endpoints of one line segment
  // cx, cy, dx, and dy are the coordinates of the endpoints of the other line segment
  // returns [x, y], the coordinates of their intersection
  // returns [NaN, NaN] if they do not intersect
  let x, y;
  if (ax === bx) {
    x = ax;
    y = cy + ((dy - cy) / (dx - cx)) * (ax - cx);
  } else if (cx === dx) {
    x = cx;
    y = ay + ((by - ay) / (bx - ax)) * (cx - ax);
  } else {
    x =
      (ay - cy + (cx * (dy - cy)) / (dx - cx) - (ax * (by - ay)) / (bx - ax)) /
      ((dy - cy) / (dx - cx) - (by - ay) / (bx - ax));
    y = ay + ((by - ay) * (x - ax)) / (bx - ax);
  }
  if (
    ((ax <= x && x <= bx) || (bx <= x && x <= ax)) &&
    ((ay <= y && y <= by) || (by <= y && y <= ay)) &&
    ((cx <= x && x <= dx) || (dx <= x && x <= cx)) &&
    ((cy <= y && y <= dy) || (dy <= y && y <= cy))
  ) {
    return [x, y];
  }
  return [0 / 0, 0 / 0];
}
```

If you cycle through the sides of the polygon and add each intersection to an array, you'll end up with `C` and `D` in that array. Depending on what you're planning to do with these points, you might want to consider a few cases:

1. `A` or `B` is inside the polygon. This might cause your array of intersections to be empty even if there are sections of `AB` that are inside of the polygon.
2. The polygon is concave (as mentioned by [Ripi2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3871028/ripi2) in their comment above). This will make it possible for the array of intersections to be longer than two points, which will make it more difficult to determine where the line is inside vs outside of the polygon.

Comment: Running through my naive implementation of this approach and found that ordering and concave polygons will both complicate this substantially. The ordering of intersections is non-trival and hard/impossible to elegantly reconcile.

Comment: @lostPixels The points can be sorted by x or y value, and then they will be in the proper order.

Comment: I ordered them by distance from the start point and solved my issues, thanks!